# Lua - direct package path to another folder in parent director

Tags: path, lua, package

I have a directory laid out :

```
-parent
    -target
    -current
        -firstChild
            -secondChild
```

I am trying to direct my package.path from inside "secondChild" to "target" to retrieve other .lua folders stashed there. I have this set up currently

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../?.lua;../?.lua;../?.lua;target/?.lua'
```

That doesn't find what I'm looking for and I'm sure that part of my problem is that I do not understand all of the syntaxes. ";../?.lua" says, to me, that I am dropping back to "firstChild" and checking to see if there are lua files?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your (updated) directory structure you need to have `../../../target/?.lua` in `package.path` to reference modules in `target` folder from `secondChild`. `?.lua` will search in `secondChild`, `../?.lua` will search in `firstChild`, `../../?.lua` will search in `current`, `../../../?.lua` will search in `parent` and `../../../target/?.lua` will search in `target` (assuming your current directory is `secondChild` when you start your script and also assuming that `-` is not part of the directory name). Having `../?.lua` only makes the search to happen in the parent of `secondChild` and having `target/?.lua` makes the search to happen in `secondChild/target/` folder, which doesn't exist.

The error message you get when you try to "require" a module includes all the paths that have been checked by the search, which usually provides a clue as to how the search path should be modified.

Comment: Perfect. I just needed to understand the format. Thank you!